# How to add Enhanced Ecommerce data to Data Layer in WooCommerce Single Product Pages?

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce, google-tag-manager

Ive added the following code to my child functions.php in WooCommerce file and its not sending the data to the data layer. Can someone tell me where the error is?

The goal is to add impression data layer info described here by google.https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce

The data in the data layer below is just sample data.

```html
/**
 * Add impression data layer to single product pages
 */

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_impdl');
function custom_impdl($product_id) {
  
 // Lets grab the product
 $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
 ?>
 <script>
// Measures product impressions and also tracks a standard
// pageview for the tag configuration.
// Product impressions are sent by pushing an impressions object
// containing one or more impressionFieldObjects.
dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'product data',
 'ecommerce': {
    'currencyCode': 'EUR',                       // Local currency is optional.
    'impressions': [
     {
       'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',       // Name or ID is required.
       'id': '12345',
       'price': '15.25',
       'brand': 'Google',
       'category': 'Apparel',
       'variant': 'Gray',
       'list': 'Search Results',
       'position': 1
     },
     {
       'name': 'Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt',
       'id': '67890',
       'price': '33.75',
       'brand': 'Google',
       'category': 'Apparel',
       'variant': 'Black',
       'list': 'Search Results',
       'position': 2
     }]
  }
});
</script>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First change your script to this:

```
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'product data',
    'ecommerce': {
    'currencyCode': 'EUR', 
    'impressions': [
     {
       'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',
       'id': '12345',
       'price': '15.25',
       'brand': 'Google',
       'category': 'Apparel',
       'variant': 'Gray',
       'list': 'Search Results',
       'position': 1
     },
     {
       'name': 'Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt',
       'id': '67890',
       'price': '33.75',
       'brand': 'Google',
       'category': 'Apparel',
       'variant': 'Black',
       'list': 'Search Results',
       'position': 2
     }]
  }
 });
</script>
```

You forgot to add the **window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({** to your script.

So your full code should look like this:

```
<?php    
/**
     * Add impression data layer to single product pages
     */
    
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_impdl');
    function custom_impdl($product_id) {
      
        // Lets grab the product
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        ?>
            <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
          'event': 'product data',
            'ecommerce': {
            'currencyCode': 'EUR', 
            'impressions': [
             {
               'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',
               'id': '12345',
               'price': '15.25',
               'brand': 'Google',
               'category': 'Apparel',
               'variant': 'Gray',
               'list': 'Search Results',
               'position': 1
             },
             {
               'name': 'Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt',
               'id': '67890',
               'price': '33.75',
               'brand': 'Google',
               'category': 'Apparel',
               'variant': 'Black',
               'list': 'Search Results',
               'position': 2
             }]
          }
         });
        </script>
    <?php
    }
```